# When will Linux Kernel 4.3-rc7 be included in Ubuntu 15.?

Tags: kernel, dvb-t

I let my desktop install the Wily Werewolf upgrade.  I discovered only one problem after the update. My dvb-t (digital tv/radio) card wouldn't work.  I found a way to get it going using modprobe, but that only works once per reboot.  Further research revealed my problem is most likely caused by a bug in the kernel: fixed in 4.3-rc7.  What I can't find though, is any kind of schedule for kernel release candidates maturing into supported components of Ubuntu. Unless I have to, I don't want to install test software on this workstation. Can anyone out there point me to where I might find this information, or make an educated guess about whether I'll be waiting days, weeks or months? Thanks

Comment: If you just need to load a module with `modprobe`, that may not require newer kernels.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it will never going to be installed in 15.10. It will be included in the next release.

If you REALLY need it then why wait if you can install it yourself?

For 15.10 64-bit a method is ...

```
 $ cd /tmp
 $ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-unstable/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300_4.3.0-040300.201511012034_all.deb
 $ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-unstable/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020846_amd64.deb
 $ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-unstable/linux-image-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020846_amd64.deb
 $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3*.deb linux-image-4.3*.deb
```

- if there is a new one change the digits
- mind the "unstable"

And you can revert back with

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.3* linux-image-4.3*
```

- The * here removes anything related to 4.3.* so so not do this in say 6 months when 4.3 is the default.

But this ...

> I found a way to get it going using modprobe, but that only works once per reboot.

will not be true. If it does not stick permanently with "modprobe" then if it works when done from commandline you can always just add it to a script and have it execute during a reboot. Bit of a hack but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If we can find the commit that fixed the bug, we can possibly get this fixed in Wily with a Stable Release Update fix.

Comment: Sorry, should have included this link in my initial question [link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103391#c23)